# Are files dumped with fwrite portable across different systems?

Tags: c++, binary, struct, fread, fwrite

Can I assume a file generated with fwrite and read using fread is portable across different systems. 32bit/64bit windows,osx,linux.

```
//dumping
FILE *of =fopen("dumped.bin","w");
double *var=new double[10];
fwrite(var, sizeof(double), 10,FILE);
//reading
file *fo=fopen()
double *var=new double[10];
fread(var,sizeof(double),10,of);
```

And what about structs

```
struct mat_t{
    size_t x;
    size_t y;
    double **matrix;
}
```

Are these portable?

Answer (score 6):

Short Answer: **NO**

Long Answer:

You are writing out the binary representation of the data.
This is not portable across platforms or OS or even compilers.

All the objects you have written have things that can change:

```
int:        size and endianess.
double:     size and representation.
structure:  Each member has to be looked at individually.
            The structure itself may be padded different on different compilers.
            Or even the same compiler with different flags.
pointers:   Are meaningless even across processes on the same machine.
            All pointers have to be converted into something meaningful like
            a named object that is provided separately. The transport will then
            have to convert named objects into pointers at the transport layer
            at the destination.
```

You have two main options:

- Streaming the data.
  This is basically converting the structure into a textual representation and sending the string. For small object, API structures this is current standard method of doing cross platform/language communication (though the data is usually wrapped in some format like XML or Json).
- Convert to a network neutral binary format
  For this we have htonl() and family of functions() for converting integers. Doubles are harder and usually converted into two integers (the values depend on accuracy requirements). Strings are converted to a length followed by a sequence of characters etc. Then each is written individually to the stream. This can be much more compact than streaming (and thus efficient). The down side is that you are tightly coupling both ends to a very specific format and thus makes the solution particularly brittle and harder to correct in error situations.

Comment: I disagree.  Binary data files are portable, although they may have to be read differently on different platforms.  Mapping the data in the file to a structure, using 1:1 mapping, most likely will not be portable due to the reasons you have stated.  Perhaps I'm being a bit pedantic here. :-(

Comment: @thomas: I did not say binary files were not portable. They are more effecient (because they are smaller) but as a result they are also more brittle and sensative to change.

Comment: Another benefit of text-based formats is that they can be directly examined.  This is a huge benefit when debugging.  It is also useful in the future, when the source code is lost and you want to recapture the data.  As in everything else, its all about tradeoffs.

Answer (score 4):

`fwrite` and `fread` are plenty portable, but you will have problems with things like `sizeof(double)`, which may vary across systems. Make sure that every binary field you write has a defined size which isn't dependent on compiler or OS--you can largely accomplish this by using the types that explicitly give their size, such as `uint32_t`.

You also have to worry about endianness, but there are macros `ntoh`, `ntohl`, `hton`, and `htonl` that you can use to swap endianness for you, and they should be defined to work correctly for whatever system you compile them on.

Comment: In addition you have to deal with how structures are packed.  Most compilers have a #pragma pack option to control that.  This will also affect performance so use carefully.

Comment: Also be wary of structs that contain pointers like the one in the question.  It's easy to forget that you need to follow the pointers to write the actual data and instead just write the now-meaningless addresses to the file.

Comment: The macros `ntoh`, `ntohl`, `hton`, and `htonl` are not part of the Standard C++ language and *may* not be available on every platform and for every compiler.

Comment: @Thomas: They are part of the posix standard.

Answer (score 1):

This file will definitely not be portable.  That's why things like [htons](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) exist.  You have to make sure your file format very clearly specifies size and [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  Since the individual types aren't portable, structs aren't either (not even considering [struct packing](http://tedlogan.com/techblog2.html)).

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing structures, and they are not self-contained (meaning they have pointers, sub-structures), you are much better off using some kind of serialization library.  There is the [Boost Serilization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library, which takes an object-oriented approach.  The output can be easily switched from text to binary, which makes debugging a lot easier.

There is also [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) (Hierarchical Data Format), a set of libraries that is routinely used in scientific computing on some unusual hardware (not your standard x86).  I've never used this, so I can't speak to how easy it is to use, but will handle huge data sets (multiple TB).

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting Windows assumes file writes are in text mode, so you need to change the "w" to "wb" in the second parameter to fwrite()

Comment: The `fwrite` function has no parameters requiring "w" or "wb", see http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/fwrite.  I believe you are referring to the `fopen` function.  See also `std::ostream::write()` and `std::ostream::open`, since this is a C++ question.